# How foreach loop works in another foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

This is the result of the code :

```
         PC
         -ASUS
         -HP
         PC2
```

But I want it to be

```
         PC
         -ASUS
         -HP
         PC2
         -ASUS
         -HP
```

Here is my code:

```
include_once "CategorieU.php";
$CategorieU=new CategorieU();
$listeCategorie=$CategorieU->afficherCategorie();
$SousCategorieU=new SousCategorieU();
$listeSousCategorie=$SousCategorieU->afficherSousCategorie();
            
foreach($listeCategorie as $cat)
{
  echo $cat['nom']."<br>";
  foreach($listeSousCategorie as $sous_cat)
     { 
       echo $sous_cat['nom']."<br>";
     }
}
```

Help please
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please provide a dump of `$listeCategorie` and `$listeSousCategorie`?

Answer (score 0):

I just make this changes and it works :D

```
   include_once "CategorieU.php";
   $CategorieU=new CategorieU();
   $listeCategorie=$CategorieU->afficherCategorie();
              
   foreach($listeCategorie as $cat)
   {
   echo $cat['nom']."<br>";
    
   $SousCategorieU=new SousCategorieU();
   $listeSousCategorie=$SousCategorieU->afficherSousCategorie();
    
   foreach($listeSousCategorie as $sous_cat)
   { 
   echo $sous_cat['nom']."<br>";
   }
   }
```